# Processing Answers to emails sent by the system

Tags: mailgun, email, ticket-system, ticket-tracking

I'm building a ticketsystem which creates tickets from incoming email automatically. The workflow look's like this:

1. User send's a email to `support@yourname.xyz`
2. The System creates a new ticket
3. A Team member answers to the ticket via a Dashboard
4. The User get a notification with the answer per email

Now I wan't to give the user the option to answer the ticket by reply to the email from step 4. But how can I assing the reply to a ticket?

Sometimes I saw solutions where the ticket id is stored in the header. The subject looks then like `[#12345] Your Request` But is there a better way to store the ticket id so the user can't see it? When I set a header variable on the email sent in Step 4, the varibale won't be included in the reply from the user.

Dose anyone have a soulution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of prefixing the ticket ID to the 'Subject' field, create a new field in your out-bound mail.  Just as you create a 'SendTo' field, also create a 'TicketID' field.  This makes the value hidden unless the recipient looks in the mail's headers.

this will then also make it easier to search for replies by the ticket number.

I think I've understood your question, but if not, please clarify.